# android jetpack navigation instrumented test fail on back navigation

Tags: android, android-espresso, back-button, android-jetpack-navigation, instrumented-test

I've created a simple, two fragment example app using jetpack `Navigation` component (`androidx.navigation`). First fragment navigates to second one, which overrides backbutton behavior with `OnBackPressedDispatcher`.

activity layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".navigationcontroller.NavigationControllerActivity">

    <fragment
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentA:

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    lateinit var buttonNavigation: Button

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false)
        buttonNavigation = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_navigation)
        buttonNavigation.setOnClickListener { Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host).navigate(R.id.fragmentB) }
        return view
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".navigationcontroller.FragmentA">
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fragment A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="go to B" />
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentB:

```
class FragmentB : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false)
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
                textView.setText("backbutton pressed, press again to go back")
                this.isEnabled = false
            }
        })
        return view
    }
}
```

---

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".navigationcontroller.FragmentA">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="fragment B" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Intended behavior of backbutton in FragmentB (first touch changes text without navigation, second navigates back) works fine when I test the app manually.
I've added instrumented tests to check backbutton behavior in FragmentB and that's where problems started to arise:

```
class NavigationControllerActivityTest {

    lateinit var fragmentScenario: FragmentScenario<FragmentB>
    lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

        fragmentScenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentB::class.java)
        fragmentScenario.onFragment(object : FragmentScenario.FragmentAction<FragmentB> {
            override fun perform(fragment: FragmentB) {
                Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
                navController.setLifecycleOwner(fragment.viewLifecycleOwner)
                navController.setOnBackPressedDispatcher(fragment.requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher())
                navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
                // simulate backstack from previous navigation
                navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentA)
                navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentB)
            }
        })
    }

    @Test
    fun whenButtonClickedOnce_TextChangedNoNavigation() {
        Espresso.pressBack()
        onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(withText("backbutton pressed, press again to go back")))
        assertEquals(R.id.fragmentB, navController.currentDestination?.id)
    }

    @Test
    fun whenButtonClickedTwice_NavigationHappens() {
        Espresso.pressBack()
        Espresso.pressBack()
        assertEquals(R.id.fragmentA, navController.currentDestination?.id)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, while `whenButtonClickedTwice_NavigationHappens` passes, `whenButtonClickedOnce_TextChangedNoNavigation` fails due to text not being changed, just like `OnBackPressedCallback` was never called. Since app works fine during manual tests, there must be something wrong with test code. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to test your `OnBackPressedCallback` logic, it is better to do that directly, rather than try to test the interaction between Navigation and the default activity's `OnBackPressedDispatcher`.

That would mean that you'd want to break the hard dependency between the activity's `OnBackPressedDispatcher` (`requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher`) and your Fragment by instead injecting in the `OnBackPressedDispatcher`, thus allowing you to provide a test specific instance:

```
class FragmentB(val onBackPressedDispatcher: OnBackPressedDispatcher) : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false)
        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
                textView.setText("backbutton pressed, press again to go back")
                this.isEnabled = false
            }
        })
        return view
    }
}
```

This allows you to have your production code [provide a FragmentFactory](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#dependencies):

```
class MyFragmentFactory(val activity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentFactory() {
    override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String): Fragment =
        when (loadFragmentClass(classLoader, className)) {
            FragmentB::class.java -> FragmentB(activity.onBackPressedDispatcher)
            else -> super.instantiate(classLoader, className)
        }
}

// Your activity would use this via:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = MyFragmentFactory(this)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // ...
}
```

This would mean you could write your tests such as:

```
class NavigationControllerActivityTest {

    lateinit var fragmentScenario: FragmentScenario<FragmentB>
    lateinit var onBackPressedDispatcher: OnBackPressedDispatcher
    lateinit var navController: TestNavHostController

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

        // Create a test specific OnBackPressedDispatcher,
        // giving you complete control over its behavior
        onBackPressedDispatcher = OnBackPressedDispatcher()

        // Here we use the launchInContainer method that
        // generates a FragmentFactory from a constructor,
        // automatically figuring out what class you want
        fragmentScenario = launchFragmentInContainer {
            FragmentB(onBackPressedDispatcher)
        }
        fragmentScenario.onFragment(object : FragmentScenario.FragmentAction<FragmentB> {
            override fun perform(fragment: FragmentB) {
                Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
                navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
                // Set the current destination to fragmentB
                navController.setCurrentDestination(R.id.fragmentB)
            }
        })
    }

    @Test
    fun whenButtonClickedOnce_FragmentInterceptsBack() {
        // Assert that your FragmentB has already an enabled OnBackPressedCallback
        assertTrue(onBackPressedDispatcher.hasEnabledCallbacks())

        // Now trigger the OnBackPressedDispatcher
        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
        onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(withText("backbutton pressed, press again to go back")))

        // Check that FragmentB has disabled its Callback
        // ensuring that the onBackPressed() will do the default behavior
        assertFalse(onBackPressedDispatcher.hasEnabledCallbacks())
    }
}
```

This avoids testing Navigation's code and focuses on testing **your** code and specifically your interaction with `OnBackPressedDispatcher`.

Comment: Could you explain what Kotlin feature is used when calling FragmentScenario.launchInContainer {...} ? It has a single argument - trailing lambda. The only version of launchInContainer  that would accept a single argument is one with default values, but it requires passing fragmentClass: Class<F> as it doesn't have default value. Why this obligatory argument could be skipped when lambda is provided for factory ? Also, FragmentFactory is not an SAM interface but a class, how could it be converted from a lambda ?

Comment: Also, this code doesn't compile in my environment, I get "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied" error. I'm using kotlin gradle plugin 1.4.31 and androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.1. How could I fix that ?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code to use the correct [`launchFragmentInContainer` extension method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/testing/package-summary#launchfragmentincontainer_3) that takes a `crossinline instantiate: () -> F` as the trailing lambda.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for FragmentB's `OnBackPressedCallback` to be ignored is the way how `OnBackPressedDispatcher` treats its `OnBackPressedCallback`s. They are run as chain-of-command, meaning that most recently registered one that is enabled will 'eat' the event so others will not receive it. Therefore, most recently registered callback inside `FragmentScenario.onFragment()` (which is enabled by `lifecycleOwner`, so whenever Fragment is at least in lifecycle `STARTED` state. Since fragment is visible during the test when backbutton is pressed, callback is always enabled at the time), will have priority over previously registered one in `FragmentB.onCreateView()`.
Therefore, `TestNavHostController`'s callback must be added before `FragmentB.onCreateView()` is executed.

This leads to changes in test code @Before method:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

    fragmentScenario = FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentB::class.java, initialState = Lifecycle.State.CREATED)
    fragmentScenario.onFragment(object : FragmentScenario.FragmentAction<FragmentB> {
        override fun perform(fragment: FragmentB) {
            navController.setLifecycleOwner(fragment.requireActivity())
            navController.setOnBackPressedDispatcher(fragment.requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher())
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
            // simulate backstack from previous navigation
            navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentA)
            navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentB)
        }
    })
    fragmentScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    fragmentScenario.onFragment(object : FragmentScenario.FragmentAction<FragmentB> {
        override fun perform(fragment: FragmentB) {
            Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
        }
    })
}
```

Most important change is to launch Fragment in `CREATED` state (instead of default `RESUMED`) to be able to tinker with it before `onCreateView()`.

Also, notice that `Navigation.setViewNavController()` is run in separate `onFragment()` after moving fragment to `RESUMED` state - it accepts `View` parameter, so it cannot be used before `onCreateView()`